# Can not make property and __getattr__ working together

Tags: python, getattr, slots

I am working on a python class that has declared properties, and in which I want to add extra attributes at object instanciation (passed in the **init** method).
I want them to be read and written.
Finally, I don't want the user to be able to declare custom attributes; it should raise an Error.

```
class Person:

    __slots__ = ["_name", "__dict__"]

    def __init__(self, name, extra_arg):
        self.__dict__[extra_arg] = None
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[item]
        raise AttributeError(item)

person = Person("gribouille", "hello")

person.custom_attribute = value # I want to prevent this
```

In this example, I can't manage to prevent new attributes to be declared.
When I override **setattr** method, it seems to collide with my property and I can't manage to retrieve my "name" attribute.

Comment: Edit the question to show the code that doesn't work and explain exactly how it doesn't work. If there are errors show them as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: If you don't want extra attributes, why are you adding `__dict__` to `__slots__` in the first place? What's the reason for letting the caller pick one arbitrary attribute to add?

Comment: Note the intentional asymmetry between `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`. `__getattr__` is only invoked when the normal attribute lookup fails; `__setattr__` is *always* invoked, not just when creating a new attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about checking for existing attributes via `hasattr` and `__slots__`?

```
class Person:

    __slots__ = ["_name", "__dict__"]

    def __init__(self, name, extra_arg):
        self.__dict__[extra_arg] = None
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[item]
        raise AttributeError(item)
        
    def __setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value):
        if not (hasattr(self, attr_name) or attr_name in self.__slots__):
            raise AttributeError(attr_name)
        super().__setattr__(attr_name, attr_value)

person = Person("gribouille", "hello")
person.name = "test"

person.custom_attribute = None # Now: AttributeError: custom_attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

> `person.custom_attribute = value # I want to prevent this`

To achieve this your class should do NOT have `__dict__` attribute, that is `__slots__` must not contain `__dict__`. Consider following simple example

```
class C1:
    __slots__ = ["__dict__"]
class C2:
    __slots__ = ["x","y"]
c1 = C1()
c1.custom = "hello"
print(c1.custom) # hello
c2 = C2()
c2.x = 10
c2.y = 30
print(c2.x,c2.y) # 10 30
c2.z = 100 # cause AttributeError: 'C2' object has no attribute 'z'
```